# Cannot install Chocolatey on Windows 10 version 1903

Tags: installation, windows-10, chocolatey

I recently upgraded my Windows 10 to version 1903, but after some issue and contacting Microsoft technical support, I've reset my Windows. Now I'm trying to reinstall everything that was installed before reset and one of them is [Chocolatey (The package manager for Windows)](https://chocolatey.org).

I tried running both [installation command](https://chocolatey.org/install):

(for cmd)

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

(for PowerShell)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

but every time I get this error:

```
Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
platform."
At C:\Users\ehsan\Downloads\install.ps1:206 char:3
+   $process.Start() | Out-Null
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Exception calling "BeginOutputReadLine" with "0" argument(s): "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process
hasn't started yet."
At C:\Users\ehsan\Downloads\install.ps1:207 char:3
+   $process.BeginOutputReadLine()
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\Users\ehsan\Downloads\install.ps1:208 char:3
+   $process.WaitForExit()
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Unable to unzip package using 7zip. Perhaps try setting $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true' and call install
again. Error: 7-Zip signalled an unknown error (code )
At C:\Users\ehsan\Downloads\install.ps1:220 char:15
+ ...   default { throw "$errorMessage 7-Zip signalled an unknown error (co ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to unzip...n error (code ):String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to unzip package using 7zip. Perhaps try setting $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompres
   sion = 'true' and call install again. Error: 7-Zip signalled an unknown error (code )
```

I also tried downloading the `install.ps1` scripts and running it manually (after setting execution policy to bypass, for sure), but the result was the same as above. Worth mentioning that I ran both cmd and PowerShell as administrator for installation. By the way, I didn't try offline installation yet, because I cannot figure out what the instruction says.

Googling the error didn't help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem (at least the message was exactly the same). I was installing chocolatey in a more controlled environment, that is, some parts of the scripts are not allowed to be performed by some security policy reason.

The error is that on line 192 of the PowerShell, it's attempted to download an EXE file:

```
Download-File 'https://chocolatey.org/7za.exe' "$7zaExe"
```

This is not allowed in my environment, so as I have the Zip already installed on my Windows, I just copy the and renamed the needed file (7az.exe) to the folder that the install.ps1 (Powershell script) was looking for.

In my case:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\7za.exe
```

So, having the ZIP exe file at this path, with this name, everything worked.

Cheers